# Why does using linker option /DYNAMICBASE speeds up my application?

Tags: visual-c++, linker

I currently do some speed measurement with a simple application and during this process I noticed that the runtime is around 1.5% shorter when I tell the linker to use /DYNAMICBASE.

I agree that 1.5% could easily be a mistake in the measuring process, but I actually did more than 15 runs with /DYNAMICBASE and 15 runs with /DYNAMICBASE:NO, each run is around 5 minutes. Not even tha fastest of the /DYNAMICBASE:NO runs was faster than the slowest /DYNAMICBASE run...

Answer (score 1):

If your solution directly or indirectly uses many DLLs - /DYNAMICBASE can lift some burden off the windows loader, especially when applied to the dependent DLLs.  When the used binaries are loaded and placed in the process address space, if their default base address ranges collide - the windows loader must *rebase* them, i.e. decide a new base address and traverse the DLL global symbol calls (data or functions) and change them to the new address.  For many - or very large - DLLs, this can have a non negligible impact on startup time.

If you run from the debugger, you can view the loaded binaries in the 'Modules' window, and inspect the icon on the left to determine whether a module underwent rebasing:

[image: Modules window]

If you see many DLLs avoid rebasing with /DYNAMICBASE, this is the likely cause. You can (and in principle should) directly control the base addresses with /BASE, and not leave this benefit to chance.